# Why is gravity divided by $2$ when you parameterize projectile motion.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm currently working on a pretty basic problem about projectile motion. No air friction, just gravity. There is a ball that is being launched from $4$ feet up at $80$ ft/sec at $40$ degrees above the horizontal. Gravity is assumed to be $32$ feet/$\text{sec}^2$. I need to parameterize it. I got $$x = 80\cos(40)$$ and $$y = 4 + t(51.4-32t) $$

My question is, when I check my answer with an online solver, why does it say that the coeffecient in the second equation, $32$, should be $16$? Why is gravity divided by $2$? Thanks for helping.

Comment: From $y''=-g$ we have $y = y_0 + v_0 t - \frac 12 g t^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When acceleration is constant, velocity changes steadily.  In a time interval, that means that the average velocity is just the average of initial and final velocities. The average of $0$ and $v$ is $\frac{v}{2}$.  If you start from rest, the final velocity is just $at$.  If you plug that into $d = vt$, you get $d = v_{avg} t = \frac{a t}{2}\cdot t = \frac{1}{2}at^2$
Similar reasoning gets you to $x = x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2} at^2$.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It explains the answer simply without calculus. Will mark as the answer in 4 minutes when I can.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of calculus.  If we assume the acceleration $a(t) = g$ for a constant $g$, we can use the fact that the velocity $a(t)$ is the derivative of the velocity (i.e. $a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt}$.  We can integrate this to find

$$
v(t) = v_0 + gt
$$

where $v_0$ is a constant of integration.  If we see that velocity is the derivative of the position $x(t)$ (i.e. $v(t) = \frac{dx}{dt}$) we can integrate one more time to obtain

$$
x(t) = x_0 + v_0t + \frac{1}{2}gt^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

The expressions for the horizontal and vertical components of the acceleration are given by:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
a_{x}(t) = 0\\\\
a_{y}(t) = -g
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Integrating both expressions, we get that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
v_{x}(t) = v_{0}\cos(\theta)\\\\
v_{y}(t) = v_{0}\sin(\theta) - gt
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Integrating both sides once again, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x(t) = x_{0} + v_{0}\cos(\theta)t\\\\
y(t) = y_{0} + v_{0}\sin(\theta)t - \dfrac{gt^{2}}{2}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Then it remains to substitute the given values at the corresponding functions.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't know calculus, I'm currently taking a precalculus class, so I don't know what integrating is, but I understand the idea. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to my own question with some more research. Gravity is divided by $2$ because if you don't, you have assumed that the velocity  has always been what it is at that point in time. Dividing by two takes the average of the velocity change from gravity since the ball was launched.

Comment: No, the gravity is constant!  You are using the constant acceleration formulas!  Gravity is an acceleration, not a speed.  ...Good correction.

Comment: Yes, I didn't make myself clear. Is my edit correct? I'm fairly new to this site.

Answer (score 0):

The upward **velocity** is $51.4-32t$. To find how high up at time $t'$, you need to take the *integral $\int_{0}^{t'} 51.4-32t)dt$, you simply cannot multiply $51.4-32t'$ by $t'$, as the upward velocity changes with time.

Answer (score 0):

The $y$-velocity at time $t$ is
$$
80\sin(40^\circ) -32t
$$
The $-32t$ term comes from gravity: for each second, the $y$-velocity decreases by $32\mathrm{ft/sec}$. That's how gravity is defined. Thus the slope of $y$-velocity is $-32$, as we see above.

Velocity is the derivative of position. In order for the derivative of $y$-position to have the gravity term $-32t$, the corresponding gravity term of $y$-position must be $-\frac{32}2t^2$ .

Answer (score 0):

The upward **velocity** at time $t$ is $51.4-32t$ i.e., a nonconstant. To find how high up the ball is at time $t'$, you need to take the *integral* of the upward velocity at time $t$, over $t$ i.e., $$y(t')=4+ \int_{0}^{t'} (51.4-32t)dt,$$ you simply cannot multiply $51.4-32t'$ by $t'$, as the upward velocity changes with time.